# PowerBuilder Runtime Packager error: Linking Msi for PowerBuilder.NET runtime get an error

Tags: windows-installer, powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy

I've just installed PowerBuilder 11.5. I'm trying to use the PowerBuilder Runtime Packager that comes with it to create an MSI with the PowerBuilder runtime DLLs. But when I hit create, about a third of the way through I get the error "Linking Msi for PowerBuilder.NET runtime get an error." (The poor English is verbatim.)

This happens both when I select "PowerBuilder Standard Components" and when I select "PowerBuilder .NET Components"

Does anyone know how to fix this?

As an aside, if XML is selected, I get an error about APACHE_LICENSE.TXT is missing. But I'm not worried about that right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that PB can find msvcr71.dll, msvcp71.dll (Visual C++ runtime) and atl71.dll (.NET Active Template Library).

Failing that, reinstall PB and try again.